# How do I incorporate microdata and rich snippets into an asp.net site with 47 pages for optimal SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engine, microdata, rich-snippets

I have a company website (asp.net/vb) in 10 different languages, although 97% of the users view it in English. I've been reading more and more about microdata and rich snippets, but I'm still confused about how to incorporate them into my website.  I've read Google Webmaster Tools, but I'm still confounded.

Where do the **itemtype** and **itemprop** span tags go? I have 5 master pages. Should I just put them in there, or would I have to create unique rich snippeets in each of the 47 pages my website has?  The main key phrase I want throughout search results is "**machine vision**".

For instance, the first couple sentences on my "about.aspx" page are:

```
USS Vision Inc. (USS) is a privately-owned company with headquarters in Detroit, 
Michigan, USA. We design, engineer, produce, and integrate special machine vision 
error-proofing products and services that create lean factories by improving the 
quality of manufactured products, and by significantly reducing manufacturing costs 
through advanced automation.
```

Should I put rich snippets in there, or can I just use the about.aspx master page, which covers about 8 other pages?  How would I do this?  Should I use the  **itemprop="url"** for every link in my website?  Any guidance in this regard to help improve my SEO and SERPS would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: itemprop="url" doesn't need to be used for every link, you can add it to your "items" which in this case could be your individual products. As for "machine vision", you can add it to your meta keywords, and to your description meta tag (if you want it to appear in the snippet below the search result). As far as microdata in general, this article could help with their use: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/09/microdata-html5s-best-kept-secret/

Comment: one more thing not seo-related, whatever you do, you should never be doing same thing manually for each of the 47 pages, that defeats the purprose of using asp.net .. you could always use nested master pages and define generic stuff as Metadescription and keywords in a central master page that all your master pages reference

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my question and respond, @Kabaros. I thought that meta keywords/phrases, tags, etc., were obsolete now, especially with google.  It'd really make it much easier if I could just put microdata on each of my 5 master pages and not have to tinker with all of my resource files.  And thank you for the link; it reinforced some of the things I thought, and taught me a couple new tricks.  I've done all I can re: SEO, quality backlinking, avoiding duplicate content, etc., and now I just want to spend this weekend incorporating microdata.  Thanks again Kabaros!

Comment: yes you're right about meta keywords, but description is used and it forms the snippet that appears underneath the search result. I don't see how microdata can be used with the example you provided but am not an expert on them, so hopefully someone will help, you could also try positing your question on Stack Webmasters